# Track UIScrollView contentOffset all the time

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I'm using a timer and print the `contentOffset.y` of a `UIScrollView` to track it **all the time**.

But the problems is `UIScrollView` updates its `contentOffset` value only after it is decelerated.

I want to know the `contentOffset.y` value in **every millisecond** of timer and how can I do that? If I cannot use `contentOffset` of the `UIScrollView` at all, is there any other way to track similar value to `contentOffset.y` of a scrollView?

I'm using swift. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the code of whatever you have tried until now?

Comment: `let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)  //declare the time

func timTick()
{
        let scrOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        print(scrOffset)
} //print every 0.01 second`       @PoojaSrivastava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of tracking the changes by polling with a timer, you can observe any changes to the value. `UIScrollView` has a `delegate` property that gets called for scroll events (see `UIScrollViewDelegate`), and `contentOffset` is KVO compliant.

Or you could subclass `UIScrollView` and try overriding the setters (either for `contentOffset` or `bounds` where `origin` is the the offset, I'm not sure which one, if either, the class calls internally - using the `delegate` is the preferred solution).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But UIScrollView delegate methods are only `WillBegin..` and `DidEnd...` methods which call only when I **finish or begin** dragging, scrolling or the scrollView itself **finish or begin** decelerating. I need to know the value **every time** whether my finger is touching the phone or not (or) the scroll View finished decelerating or not. I don't have any idea how to override the setters that you mentioned. @Arkku

Comment: @thuraoo The `scrollViewDidScroll:` is being called during scroll whenever the offset changes, not only begin/end. (Just try it.) Inside that method you can check `isDragging`, `isTracking` and/or `isDecelerating` properties of the scroll view. You can also override the `willBegin` and `didEnd` for dragging and/or decelerating if you need some special handling at those events.

Comment: @thuraoo As for how to override the setters, as you would override any method (remember to call the `super` implementation). But it is highly unlikely to be necessary, I have done a lot of stuff that requires accurately tracking the scroll view's movements and `scrollViewDidScroll:` of the delegate is almost always sufficient.

Comment: @thuraoo In any case, a timer is a _horrible_ solution to the problem. You will be calling it unnecessarily most of the time, your app will wake up for the pointless timer 100 times a second, and in the end the responsiveness will still be worse than tracking the actual changes.

Comment: Now my problem is solved. As the method says `scrollViewDidScroll` I thought that it will call only after decelerating. Now I tried it and it works. **Thank you very much** for you answers and comments.